# How to add manufacturer details in grouprd product?

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.3, grouped-products, manufacturer

i want to show manufacturer details in grouped product.
but i am not getting the manufacturer attribute in product detail page.
For reference please find the attached image.
[image]

Comment: manufacturer means which attribute you have talking about?

Comment: we have to show the Brand Name

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in your **catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml** file,

path : **app/design/frontend/[your_theme]/Magento_GroupedProduct/layout**

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.customattribute" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getBrand</argument>
                <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">brand</argument>
                <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">brand</argument>
                <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="brand"</argument>
                <argument name="at_type" xsi:type="string">text</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
```

And also you can use the **own brand attribute code** instead of **brand**

Comment: i am not getting brand option only for Grouped Products

Comment: add the above code in catalog_product_view_type_grouped.xml file

Comment: Answer is updated.